# How does a woman offer kaffarah when she can not fast consecutively because of menses?

Tags: women, menses, kaffarah

so i already know that if one breaks a fast intentionally, they have to either feed 60 poor people or fast for 60 consecutuve days without skipping any days. however, this isnt possible for most women as they'll most likely get their period twice in those 60 days. this is pretty much unavoidable, so, when a woman is fasting for 60 days as punishment for breaking her fast intentionally, after her period ends, does she just continue counting her fasts from she left off when her period started?

Answer (score 2):

For a woman the requirement of consecutive fasting for kaffarah is not violated when she is prevented from fasting due to menstruation. So she will pause fasting in her period and then continue after it is over.

> الحيض لا يقطع التتابع في صوم كفارة القتل والوقاع في رمضان إن لزمتها كفارة
>
> <sup>— [Nawawi - Rawdat al-Talibeen](https://al-maktaba.org/book/499/3412)</sup>